# Facing issue in using mv() module in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

encountering with error ENOENT : rename filename,
am unable to understand this error why am facing can anyone help me out.
below is my code

```
mv(query.sourceLocation, query.targetLocation, {
mkdirp: true
  }, function (err) {
if (err) return console.error(err+new Date());
res.end("moved");
});
```

Comment: Does `query.sourceLocation` point to a valid path?

Comment: Yes, am facing this issue only for some times and not all the times,